# angular2 unit test: cannot read property of componentInstance.method() undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

mycomponent.spec.ts class:

This throws error: Cannot read property 'ngOnInit' of undefined.

```
let myComponent: MyComponent;
let myService: MyService;

describe('myComponent', () => {
   beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
    providers: [
      {provide: MyService, useClass: MockMyService} // **--passing Mock service**
  ]
}).compileComponents()
  .then(() => {
    myComponent = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent).componentInstance;
    myService = TestBed.get(MyService);
    console.log(myService.getData());
  });
});

it('should get the mock data', () => {
   myComponent.ngOnInit(); //-----------> seems like myComponent is not defined at this place, how to resolve this error 
   expect(myComponent.data).toBe(DATA_OBJECT);
  });
});
```

below is MyComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'pm-catalogs',
  templateUrl: './catalog-list.component.html'
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

 public data: IData[];

 constructor(private _myService: MyService) {

}

public ngOnInit(): void {
this._myService.getData()
  .subscribe(
    data => this.data = data
  //  error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
  );
 }
}
```

below is mock service

```
  export const DATA_OBJECT: IData[] = [
 {
   'Id': 1,
   'value': 'abc'
 },
 {
'Id': 2,
'value': 'xyz'
 }];

@Injectable()
export class MockMyService {
 public getData(): Observable<IData[]> {
    return Observable.of(DATA_OBJECT);
  }
}
```

I am newbie to Angular2 testing and I want myService.getData to return DATA_OBJECT when myComponent.ngOnInit() calls myService.getData() method in my spec class
Please help me to achieve that.

Comment: The code in `describe` block is badly indented, it isn't clear what is going on there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that asynchronous `beforeEach` is incorrectly implemented, this results in race condition.

Doing `.compileComponents().then(() => { ... })` in `beforeEach` block results in delaying code execution in `then` callback at least for one tick. `it` block never waits and accesses `myComponent` variable before it had a chance to be assigned.

This kind of race conditions can become less obvious and more dangerous when a test doesn't fail. Instead, tests can become cross-contaminated when `beforeEach` from previous tests affects variables in current test.

`.compileComponents()` is synchronous, unless there are components with `styleUrls` and `templateUrl` (like in the case above). In this case it becomes asynchronous, and `async` helper should be used:

```
// asynchronous block
beforeEach(async(() => {    
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({ ... })
  .compileComponents();
}));

// synchronous block
beforeEach(() => {    
  myComponent = ...
});
```

As a rule of thumb, blocks should be wrapped with `async` of `fakeAsync` helper if there's a chance that block can be asynchronous.

When component classes are tested with `TestBed`, they follow a lifecycle and their hooks are called automatically. Calling `ngOnInit()` manually is not needed (as another answer explains) and will result in calling the hook twice.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to call `ngOnInit()` manually to run the component's init().

Modify your code to below code

```
let myComponent: MyComponent;
let myService: MyService;
let fixture;

describe('myComponent', () => {
   beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
    providers: [
      {provide: MyService, useClass: MockMyService} // **--passing Mock service**
  ]
}).compileComponents()
  .then(() => {
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    myComponent = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent).componentInstance;
    myService = TestBed.get(MyService);
    console.log(myService.getData());
  });
});

it('should get the mock data', () => {
   fixture.detectChanges();  // this line will call components ngOnInit() method
   expect(myComponent.data).toBe(DATA_OBJECT);
  });
})
```

Look at the line `fixture.detectChanges();` First time when change detection happens components `ngOnInit()` will be called.

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks. And this is how angular/cli schematics should generate the spec files (`.compileComponents().then()`)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone doesn't find the accepted answer helpful, this error also **may come** when `NgZone` isn't mocked properly. I don't understand the underlaying mechanics, but a was previously providing mocked `NgZone` as an object literal like follows:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [{
        provide: NgZone,
        useValue: {
            runOutsideAngular: (fn: (...args: Array<any>) => T) => { return fn(); }
            ... other NgZone functions ...
        }
    }],
    declarations: [MyComponent]
})
```

This worked in some tests for some reason, so I wasn't suspecting it at first but after a while I created a mocked `NgZone` class which extends the actual `NgZone`:

```
export class NgZoneMock extends NgZone {
    constructor() {
        super({ enableLongStackTrace: false });
    }

    public runOutsideAngular<T>(fn: (...args: Array<any>) => T) { return fn(); }
    public run<T>(fn: (...args: Array<any>) => T, applyThis?: any, applyArgs?: Array<any> | undefined) { return fn(); }
    public runTask<T>(fn: (...args: Array<any>) => T, applyThis?: any, applyArgs?: Array<any> | undefined) { return fn(); }
    public runGuarded<T>(fn: (...args: Array<any>) => T, applyThis?: any, applyArgs?: Array<any> | undefined) { return fn(); }
    public onUnstable = new EventEmitter<any>();
    public onStable = new EventEmitter<any>();
    public onMicrotaskEmpty = new EventEmitter<any>();
    public onError = new EventEmitter<any>();
}
```

Then just the class in the `TestBed` configuration:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [{
        provide: NgZone,
        useClass: NgZoneMock
    }],
    declarations: [MyComponent]
})
```

It is worth mentioning that there are other ways to do this (and for mocking any service in general). Here's a few examples [Running jasmine tests for a component with NgZone dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47503064/running-jasmine-tests-for-a-component-with-ngzone-dependency). Creating a Jasmine Spy Object is pretty useful but I personally prefer mocks to be in separate files next to the actual service file for DRY. Of course you could put the Spy Object in to the mock file as well.