# How to create mock NgZone in angular testing

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have a component that takes NgZone as a provider. How can I make a provider for NgZone when creating the TestBed.

I tried this but the test is timing out

```
const mockNgZone = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockNgZone', ['run', 'runOutsideAngular'])
mockNgZone.run.and.callFake(fn => fn())
```

When I use this mockNgZone, the test is timing out with the error:

```
Disconnected (1 times), because no message in 10000 ms.
Electron 1.7.9 (Node 7.9.0) ERROR
   Disconnected, because no message in 10000 ms.
```

Comment: mockNgZone.run.and.CallFake(function () {return something;});. The run and runOutsideAngular return value from the executed function.

Comment: @notionquest, your answer worked. Can you write your comment as an answer? I'll mark it as correct 

also write the same answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47503064/running-jasmine-tests-for-a-component-with-ngzone-dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `run` and `runOutsideAngular` methods of `NgZone` return value from the executed function. So, please return some value from the `callFake` function.

**Example:-**

```
mockNgZone.run.and.callFake(function () {return something;});
```

Comment: Hi in my case this worked: ```mockNgZone.run.and.callFake((fn:any)=>fn())``` , If I put : ```mockNgZone.run.and.callFake((fn:any)=>'something')```, I get a error.,